# Car is not moving right?

Tags: java, oop

[image]Car is moving but as it reaches column 5 it stops there and does not move.

Car has the `move()` method, in which Car instances drive forwards with the amount of cells equivalent to speed in each time step (from left to right).

Car shall accelerate its speed by 1 after each time step and the speed for the next time step will be higher

```
public class Car extends Actor {

        public  final int MAXSPEED= 5;
        private int speed = 3;


        public void move() {
            Grid<Actor> gr = this.getGrid();
            if (gr != null) {
                Location loc = this.getLocation();
                Location next = new Location(0,this.speed);
                if (gr.isValid(next)) {
                    this.moveTo(next);
                } else {
                    this.removeSelfFromGrid();
                }
            }
        }

 public void accelerate(){

            if (this.speed <5) {
             //   move();
                this.speed++;
            } else {
                this.speed = MAXSPEED;
            }
        }

        public void dawdle(){

            if(Math.random() <= 0.3){

               this.speed= speed--;

            }else{
                this.speed=speed;
            }


        }


  public Car(){

            if (speed==1){
                this.setColor(Color.red);
            }
            else if (speed==5){
                this.setColor(Color.green);
            }
    }

  


    @Override
    public void act(){

            this.move();
           this.accelerate();
           this.dawdle();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: I tried that but i was not able to step into move()

Comment: @NSD Where's your main method?

Comment: It is in a separate file.  public class RacingCarWorld extends ActorWorld {

    private static CarGrid world = new CarGrid();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActorWorld actorWorld = new ActorWorld();

       Car car1 = new Car();
       world.add(new Location(0,0),car1);
       world.show();

    }

}

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Your accelerate function allows the car to have a maximum speed of 5.
Together with your move function, which contains

```
 Location next = new Location(0,this.speed);
```

the car will never go beyond position 5. I think you know what needs to be changed:

newlocation = currentLocation + speed

I do not see anything like this in your code.

Comment: but when the speed reaches to maxspeed it should move with the gap of 5 columns. Not come to a standstill.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more verbose. Got it now?

Answer (score 0):

To move the car i needed the car current position so speed can be added into the current position to move the car.

Location next = new Location(loc.getRow(),loc.getCol()+this.speed);